# How to use my index.htm in this location?

Tags: nginx

I need http://suporte.ok.org.br redirecting to its `index.htm` (see `root` directive), not rewriting it to Github... How to do it? All are in production, is a concrete case.

---

I was testing many variations of `location = / { try_files ...}` but no one works. Using a UBUNTU 16 LTS server.

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/ok.org.br`

```
server {
        server_name  suporte.ok.org.br;

        root   /var/www/suporte.ok.org.br;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        #?? location =/ {...} is not working!


    location / {
            rewrite
              ^/?git$
              http://github.com/okfn-brasil/suporte
              break;
            rewrite
              ^/?([vV][\.\d]+)$
              http://github.com/okfn-brasil/suporte/tree/$1​
              break;
            rewrite
              ^/?tickets$
              http://github.com/okfn-brasil/suporte/issues
              break;
            rewrite
              ^/?(?:(?:tic|ticket)/)?(\d+)$
              http://github.com/okfn-brasil/suporte/issues/$1
              break;
            rewrite
              ^/?(.+)$
              http://github.com/okfn-brasil/suporte/$1
              break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain a lot better what you want to achieve and how that fails.

Comment: @Sven wait, I will explain: I need http://suporte.ok.org.br/ working fine, with `index.htm`

Comment: This explains nothing. How are the rewrite rules related, what content is in the directories. Give us the whole picture. And don't add information in comments, edit your question instead. [How to ask better questions on Serverfault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)

Comment: @Sven, Hi, I edited, check if it is better.

Comment: OK, from what I gather you want to have the redirect to github for nearly everything, but want just `/` to not redirect, is that correct?

Comment: @Sven, thanks, Yes. For root access (`/`), I need to show the local (my server)  `index.htm`